# In Matlab, what is the difference in class between sym('x') and sym('1-x')?

Tags: matlab, function, compiler-errors, symbolic-math

I have defined the following function:

```
function y = pos(c)
% function outputs the maximum of c and 0 
%ie. pos(c)=0 if c is negative, and pos(c)=c if c is positive
if isa(c,'sym')
    y=sym(strcat('pos(',c,')'));
elseif isa(c,'double')
    y=max(c,0);
else
    y='not defined';
end
```

It works fine if I input a symbol of the form sym('x'):

```
>> pos(sym('x'))

ans =

pos(x)
```

However, if I apply it to a symbol of the form sym('1-x') I get an error:

```
>> pos(sym('1-x'))
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Error in strcat (line 94)
        s(pos:pos+len-1) = str;

Error in pos (line 6)
    y=sym(strcat('pos(',c,')'));
```

Why is this? I assume there is something different about the nature of sym('x') and sym('1-x')?

Comment: Thanks, do you know how would I go about applying my function to 1-x, with x symbolic? I have tried:

    pos(1-sym('c'))

To no avail.

Comment: I recommend [using the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to see what value of `c` you're trying to concatenate.

Comment: This gives me the answer I need (ie. pos(1-x)) but I think that storing the variable as a string will cause issues in calling the function from within another function where I need x to remain symbolic?

function y = pos(c)
% function outputs the maximum of c and 0 
%ie. pos(c)=0 if c is negative, and pos(c)=c if c is positive
if isa(c,'sym')
    y=sym(strcat('pos(',char(c),')'));
elseif isa(c,'double')
    y=max(c,0);
else
    y='not defined';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string manipulation is not a good idea to substitute variables.

To give an alternative for the relevant part:

```
if isa(c,'sym')
    %create a symbolic function pos
    f=symfun(sym('pos(h)'),sym('h'))
    %substitute the parameters
    y=f(c)
elseif
```